# Rotating table, LINQ syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following SQL and result:

```
SELECT*FROM StockLines WHERE ID in('A','B') AND Stock>=1100 AND Stock<=1105
-- RESULT
Stock   ID  Value
1100    A   398.02
1100    B   1803.62
1101    A   480.07
1101    B   1794.89
1102    A   583.24
1102    B   1800.43
1103    A   528.9
1103    B   1808.26
1104    A   556.14
1104    B   1801.77
1105    A   454.87
1105    B   1778.83
```

I use the following SQL to rotate the table:

```
SELECT
    Stock, 
    MIN (CASE ID WHEN 'A' THEN VALUE END) [A],
    MIN (CASE ID WHEN 'B' THEN VALUE END) [B]
FROM 
    StockLines 
WHERE 
    Stock>=1100 AND Stock<=1105
GROUP BY Stock
-- RESULT
Stock   A   B
1100    398.02  1803.62
1101    480.07  1794.89
1102    583.24  1800.43
1103    528.9   1808.26
1104    556.14  1801.77
1105    454.87  1778.83
```

The question is: How to write the second SQL in LINQ?

Answer (score 3):

I used LINQ to Objects for this, but this syntax should work fine with LINQ to SQL:

```
void Main()
{
    var items = new List<StockItem>();
    items.Add(new UserQuery.StockItem { ID = "A", Value = 398.02m, Stock = 1100});
    items.Add(new UserQuery.StockItem { ID = "B", Value = 1803.62m, Stock = 1100});
    items.Add(new UserQuery.StockItem { ID = "A", Value = 480.07m, Stock = 1100});
    items.Add(new UserQuery.StockItem { ID = "B", Value = 1794.89m, Stock = 1100});
    items.Add(new UserQuery.StockItem { ID = "A", Value = 583.24m, Stock = 1100});
    items.Add(new UserQuery.StockItem { ID = "B", Value = 1800.43m, Stock = 1100});
    var query = from item in items
                group item by new { item.Stock }
                into stocks
                select new { 
                    Stock = stocks.Key.Stock, 
                    A = stocks.Where(stock => stock.ID == "A").Min(stock => stock.Value), 
                    B = stocks.Where(stock => stock.ID == "B").Min(stock => stock.Value) 
                };
}

public class StockItem
{
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `stocks.First().Stock` can be replaced by `stocks.Key.Stock`. Also I don't think `First()` can be used (use `FirstOrDefault()`).

Comment: @KingKing Modified answer

Comment: The answer is correct. Works fine. Thank you. - Note: the Values in your sample, last fouw rows,  has to be correcto to 1001,1001,1002, and 1002

Comment: Doesn't work if some of the `Where` returns empty set. Note that due to `group by` the `stocks` are never empty, but the same cannot be said when applying additional filtering.

Answer (score 3):

If we realize that this SQL snippet

```
MIN (CASE ID WHEN 'A' THEN VALUE END)
```

is just a shortcut for

```
MIN (CASE ID WHEN 'A' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END)
```

then the corresponding Linq query naturally would look like this

```
    var StockLines = new[]
    {
        new { Stock = 1100, ID = "A", Value = 398.02m },
        new { Stock = 1100, ID = "B", Value = 1803.62m },
        new { Stock = 1101, ID = "A", Value = 480.07m },
        new { Stock = 1101, ID = "B", Value = 1794.89m },
        new { Stock = 1102, ID = "A", Value = 583.24m },
        new { Stock = 1102, ID = "B", Value = 1800.43m },
        new { Stock = 1103, ID = "A", Value = 528.9m },
        new { Stock = 1103, ID = "B", Value = 1808.26m },
        new { Stock = 1104, ID = "A", Value = 556.14m },
        new { Stock = 1104, ID = "B", Value = 1801.77m },
        new { Stock = 1105, ID = "A", Value = 454.87m },
        new { Stock = 1105, ID = "B", Value = 1778.83m },
    };
    var query =
        from line in StockLines
        where line.Stock >= 1100 && line.Stock <= 1105
        group line by line.Stock into lines
        select new
        {
            Stock = lines.Key,
            A = lines.Min(item => item.ID == "A" ? (decimal?)item.Value : null),
            B = lines.Min(item => item.ID == "B" ? (decimal?)item.Value : null),
        };
```

Comment: This response is better because supports the lack of any line and retains the matrix integrity. Thank you.